# Reading .txt file to tab in R

Tags: r, file, save

I want to read .txt file in R which is exported by this lines:

```
cat(sprintf("%s\n",paste0(matematykData)),file=nazwapliku2,append = TRUE)
```

The line is in loop so it saves it line by line, and the variable matematykData is a 1dim tab that contains only one record which is replaced by another record on the next run of "for loop" and it looks like this:

```
[1] "1884"
```

The reading method i use in another R script is:

```
dane2=read.table(file=nazwapliku2,sep="\n",skipNul= FALSE)
```

From this i get a string without any rows and columns that looks like this:

```
2962   1847
2963   1866
2964   1906
2965    429
2966    450
2967    450
2968   1910
2969   1900
2970   1889
```

Where the first "column" is the number of line. I want to convert that string to tab so i can reffrence every row of it, simply by using dane2[i] where "i" is the number of row i'am looking for. I'm not sure if i should change the way it's beening saved or readed or should i just read it and then convert it.

I also have other variable that needs to be converted and its more complicated because it contains 3 records per row: full_name,date and place of birth,date and place of death. The method i use for saving it is the same:

```
cat(sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",paste0(matematyk[1]),paste0(matematyk[2]),paste0(matematyk[3])),file=nazwapliku1,append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Don't use sep="\n" here

Comment: So which separator i should use then ? \t ?

Comment: You should use the separator you used between elements in your single lines.

Comment: Changing that does not seem to have any impact on that. The input i get from file by reading it is still a single string. Maybe there's a way to use strsplit or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case it should work with dane2[i] for the row number.

You have to distinguish between records and variables.
In the second case I understand it that you have several records, each with the 5 variables

full_name, date of birth, place of birth, date of death, place of death

In that case you need to change your way of saving your data. In between the variables you need to use for example \t to separate the variables, and only use \n as the last in your format string for sprintf() call to separate the individual records.